# Zend Framework and Cubique grid - LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, join

I have a simple grid in my Zend Framework application:

```
$grid = new Cubique_Grid('user');
$grid->setTable('user')
    ->setColumns(array(
        'name'      => 'Name',
        'interests' => 'Interests'
    ))
    ->setDefaultOrder('name')
    ->setColumnsToSort(array('name', 'interests'))
    ->setColumnsToEscape(array('name', 'interests'))
    ->setColumnsToSearch(array('name', 'interests'))
    ->setJoin('interest', 'interest', 'interest_id', 'id', 'name')
    ->logErrors(APPLICATION_PATH . '/logs/cubique');
```

And I have a problem in my JOIN. It seems that Cubique make `LEFT JOIN`, but I need `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Are you know how can I make it in Cubique?
Cubique on [GitHub](https://github.com/plutov/cubique)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer:

Currently Cubique supports only LEFT JOIN.